# Mostrar notificación en una hora/fecha específica

Tags: android, android-studio

**Buenas, tengo una duda, ¿Cómo se programa una notificación para que se muestre, por ejemplo, el 03/09/2020 a las 00:00?

Entiendo que de esta manera puedo mostrar la notificación:

```
    btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    NotificationCompat.Builder crearNotificacion = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning)
                            .setLargeIcon((((BitmapDrawable)getResources()
                            .getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)).getBitmap()))
                            .setContentTitle("¡Atención!")
                            .setContentText("Se ha habilitado un nuevo audio.")
                            .setContentInfo("4")
                            .setTicker("¡Alerta!");
    
                    Intent notificacion = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VideoIntroduccion.class);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(VideoIntroduccion.this, 0, notificacion,0);
                    crearNotificacion.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    
                    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICAR_ALERTA_ID, crearNotificacion.build());
                }
            });
```

Esto debería funcionar, pero a mi no me funciona. Lo que necesito es que se visualice la notificación en una hora y fecha específica, ¿Alguien sabe como lograrlo?

Comment: Te puede servir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36902667/how-to-schedule-notification-in-android

Comment: Con AlarmManager lo puedes realizar , agregue respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código que tienes solo genera la Notificación, para mostrar una notificación en una hora/fecha específica implementa la clase `AlarmManager`

Ejemplo:

**AlarmManager, mostrar alerta en una hora y fecha específica**.

Crea una clase que extienda de `BroadcastReceiver` y aquí es donde llamarías la creación de la notificación :

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class OnAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          Log.i("ALARM","Alarm activated! " + System.currentTimeMillis());

          //Aquí llama tu notificación.


    }

}
```

declara como receiver la clase en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
    ...
    ...
    <receiver android:name="com.jorgesys.app1.OnAlarmReceiver" />

</application>
```

Realiza esto para configurar una alerta, por ejemplo el día Septiembre, 2 del 2020 a las 4:30:00

```
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), OnAlarmReceiver.class);
   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 123, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
   AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
           
    Calendar myAlarmDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    myAlarmDate.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    //Define fecha y hora  : Septiembre (9-1), 2 del 2020 a las 4:30:00
    myAlarmDate.set(2020, 9-1, 2, 16, 30, 0);
    Log.i(TAG, "AlarmX set in : " + myAlarmDate.getTime().toString());

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            myAlarmDate.getTimeInMillis(),
            pendingIntent);
```